# How to make a update hook that prevents non-UTF-8 file encoding

Tags: git, version-control, githooks

I need to prevent server-side non-UTF-8 files from being pushed into the repository. I wrote the script below, but at line 12 the command `file -bi <file>` does not work because the file is not found.
I want to check the encoding of versions of files that are "coming" in push.

My intention is: First I list the files that are in diff, then I go one by one and check encoding and lastly if it's UTF-8 ok ...if not i reject a push and send msg error

```sh
#!/bin/sh -xv

refname="$1"
oldrev="$2"
newrev="$3"
filesDiff="`git diff-tree --no-commit-id -r ${newrev} | awk '{print $6}'`" 
numFiles="`git diff-tree --no-commit-id -r ${newrev} | wc -l`"

for (( i=1; i<=$numFiles; i++ ))  
    do
        arquivo=`echo $filesDiff | awk '{print $'$i'}'`
        encoding=`file -bi $arquivo | awk '{print $2}'`
        if $($encoding | grep -q 'utf-8'); then
            exit 0
        else
            echo "O arquivo $arquivo precisa estar com encoding UTF-8"
            echo "Atualmente o ${encoding}."
            echo "Verifique maiores informações em:"
            echo "https//:site.com.br/etc/etc"
            exit 1
        fi
    done
```

The out of `file -bi <file>` is open...

Answer (score 2):

You could instead use an approach similar to "[GIT pre-commit hook which searches non-UTF-8 encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55651011/6309)", base on piping your diff to `| xargs -I {} bash -c '... your command...'`

That would allow iconv to operate on the file content, checking if it represents an utf-8 content or not.